# Python RandomForest - Unknown label Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have trouble using RandomForest fit function

This is my training set

```
         P1      Tp1           IrrPOA     Gz          Drz2
0        0.0     7.7           0.0       -1.4        -0.3
1        0.0     7.7           0.0       -1.4        -0.3
2        ...     ...           ...        ...         ...
3        49.4    7.5           0.0       -1.4        -0.3
4        47.4    7.5           0.0       -1.4        -0.3
... (10k rows)
```

I want to predict P1 thanks to all the other variables using sklearn.ensemble RandomForest

```
colsRes = ['P1']
X_train = train.drop(colsRes, axis = 1)
Y_train = pd.DataFrame(train[colsRes])
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([[  0. ],
       [  0. ],
       [  0. ],
       ..., 
       [ 49.4],
       [ 47.4],
```

I did not find anything about this label error, I use Python 3.5.
Any advice would be a great help !

Comment: which version of sklearn you are using?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you are passing label (y) data to  `rf.fit(X,y)`, it expects y to be 1D list. Slicing the Panda frame always result in a 2D list. So, conflict raised in your use-case. You need to convert the 2D list provided by pandas DataFrame to a 1D list as expected by fit function.

Try using 1D list first:

```
Y_train = list(train.P1.values)
```

If this does not solve the problem, you can try with solution mentioned in [MultinomialNB error: "Unknown Label Type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722986):

```
Y_train = np.asarray(train['P1'], dtype="|S6")
```

So your code becomes,

```
colsRes = ['P1']
X_train = train.drop(colsRes, axis = 1)
Y_train = np.asarray(train['P1'], dtype="|S6")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Comment: I understand the problem now, but your code does not do the work. I am looking for other ways to do the conversion

Comment: Can you try with `Y_train = list(train.P1.values)`? Let me know the error message if there is any

Comment: Error message does not change.
Y_train shape looks good though

print(Y_train)

[  0.    0.    0.  ...,  49.4  47.4  45.4]

Y shape gives (34208,)    -  #34208 is the number of rows

Comment: Thanks for the error message. Can you try this: `Y_train = np.asarray(train['P1'], dtype="|S6")`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! My PC crashed three times because it could not support the calculus though...

Answer (score 9):

> According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915940/error-using-extratreesclassifier-in-scikit-learn), **Classifiers need integer or string labels**.

You could consider switching to a regression model instead (that *might* better suit your data, as each datum appears to be a float), like so:

```
X_train = train.drop('P1', axis=1)
Y_train = train['P1']
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train.as_matrix(), Y_train.as_matrix())
```

Comment: Thanks but no difference

Comment: From what I understand about complete error report, from the line where I call the 'fit' function

From the report:
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 235, in fit
y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
...

Comment: @Dragonfly, I'm terribly sorry for taking so long, but I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I think even strings can be used instead of floats.

Comment: @GurupadHedge, yes they can! But since this data is just floats, a regression solution _might_ be a more sensible option.

Comment: Looking into the problem, as all fields in training set are floats. So, I think **regression** be more useful than classifier.

Comment: Regression works fine! Thanks a lot ! I used RandomForestRegressor instead of ExtraTreesRegressor. I will try to figure out the difference between those two

Answer (score 1):

may be a tad late to the party but I just got this error and solved it by making sure my y variable was type(int) using

```
 y = df['y_variable'].astype(int)
```

before doing a train test split, also like others have said you problem seems better fit with a RFReg rather then RF

Comment: 'y_variable'  spelling