# Python returning Unknown label type: (array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

i have being a trouble running the following code below, which he was supposed to fit both training predictors and training class. Idk what is happening right now, i tried debug but i get nothing in return, seems the problem comes from this slice of my code:

**PROBLEM I THINK IT'S**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
classificador = MLPClassifier(verbose = True,
                              max_iter=1000,
                              tol = 0.0000010,
                              solver = 'adam',
                              hidden_layer_sizes=(100),
                              activation='relu')
classificador.fit(previsores_treinamento, classe_treinamento)
previsoes = classificador.predict(previsores_teste)
```

**HERE ARE ALL MY CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base = pd.read_csv("credit_data.csv")
base.loc[base['age'] < 0] = 40.92 

previsores = base.iloc[:,1:4].values
classe = base.iloc[:,4].values

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(previsores[:, 1:4])
previsores[:, 1:4] = imputer.transform(previsores[:, 1:4])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
previsores = scaler.fit_transform(previsores)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
previsores_treinamento, previsores_teste, classe_treinamento, classe_teste = train_test_split(previsores, classe, test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
classificador = MLPClassifier(verbose = True,
                              max_iter=1000,
                              tol = 0.0000010,
                              solver = 'adam',
                              hidden_layer_sizes=(100),
                              activation='relu')
classificador.fit(previsores_treinamento, classe_treinamento)
previsoes = classificador.predict(previsores_teste)
```

Comment: @MZ Sr i'm not having "passive aggressive atitude", i tried to clerify my post soo you can better understand. Despite of this, when i did some linear regression i never needed use `np.narray` at the moment of  fit in my training_previsors/training_class, why now? I know when i split my data with `train_test_split' returns to me a tuple...

Comment: @MZ i checked and both are `np.ndarray`.
 Since here 
`previsores = base.iloc[:,1:4].values
classe = base.iloc[:,4].values` and after the split.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Unknown label type: while implementing MLPClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713276/valueerror-unknown-label-type-while-implementing-mlpclassifier)

Comment: @MZ `classe_treinamento.astype(int)` returns `array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])`

Comment: yes, I know, I mean *use* `classe_treinamento.astype(int)` in your `fit` method

Comment: @MZ seems its worked. I aways need to use `astype(int)` in the `fit` method in MLPClassifier?

Comment: for your target value `y`. Please read the documentation. Always needs to be of type int at least, you had floats

Comment: @MZ i asked because, in a course im taking from Udemy, the instructor didn't use anything to convert float to int and works for him and i was wondering why not worked with me...btw thanks for you help!